# Remove header title from react-navigation

Tags: typescript, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm using `react-navigation` version 6 and would like to know how to remove that title from the header, which comes by default, already displaying the name of the page that we pass.

In version 5, passing to `headerMode` this was already removed, but in this new version I didn't find how it can be removed.

My code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import { Home } from '../screens/Home';
import { Search } from '../screens/Search';

const { Navigator, Screen } = createStackNavigator();

export function AppStackRoutes() {
  return (
    <Navigator initialRouteName="Search">
      <Screen 
        name="Search" 
        component={Search} 
      />
      <Screen 
        name="Home" 
        component={Home} 
      />
    </Navigator>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `headerShown` to hide or show the title bar.

Read [this migration guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x/#headermodenone-is-removed-in-favor-of-headershown-false) and from the doc:

> Previously, you could pass headerMode="none" prop to hide the header in a stack navigator. However, there is also a headerShown option which can be used to hide or show the header, and it supports configuration per screen.

```js
<Navigator 
    initialRouteName="Search" 
    screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
>
    <Screen 
        name="Search" 
        component={Search} 
    />
    <Screen 
        name="Home" 
        component={Home} 
    />
</Navigator>
```

Comment: This hides the whole header, not just the header title

Answer (score 4):

set the `headerTitle` to an empty string, to hide title name

```js
<Navigator 
    initialRouteName="Search" 
    screenOptions={{ headerTitle: '' }}
>
    <Screen 
        name="Search" 
        component={Search} 
    />
    <Screen 
        name="Home" 
        component={Home} 
    />
</Navigator>
```

Comment: This, although I should have just thought of that in retrospect (I tried setting to null)... is better.  The accepted answer hides the whole header bar, no? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I've used, headerTitleStyle to hide my title of header, It worked as expected [ReactNavigationVersion 6]

```
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Search"
    component={Search}
    options={{
      headerTitleStyle: {display: 'none'},
      headerRight: () => {
        return <SearchBoxComponent />;
      },
    }}
  />
```